# .ICS file is not being added correctly to Outlook Calender

Tags: calendar, outlook, icalendar

I am trying to figure out why this ICS file (Exported from an LMS) is being added as an 'All Day Event' on Tue, 16 June 2015 when it should only be listed for 13:30 – 14:30. When I import this in to Google Calender, I do not get the same issue.

Here's a text dump of the ICS file in question:

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
PRODID:-//ddaysoftware.com//NONSGML DDay.iCal 1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;CN=Alyssa Hilliard;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT:MAILTO:Email Address]
ATTENDEE;CN=Admin Admin;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT:MAILTO:[Email Address]
DESCRIPTION:[DESCRIPTION]
DTSTAMP:20141001T163752Z
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20141106
ORGANIZER:mailto:[Email Address]
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:[Summary]
UID:185f5bcf-3304-48e6-b281-9eb040bb3453
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;CN=Alyssa Hilliard;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT:MAILTO:Email Address]
ATTENDEE;CN=Admin Admin;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT:MAILTO:Email Address]
DESCRIPTION:[DESCRIPTION]
DTSTAMP:20141001T163752Z
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20150808
ORGANIZER:mailto:Email Address]
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:[Summary]
UID:185f5bcf-3304-48e6-b281-9eb040bb3453
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

Answer (score 1):

This is a badly setup ics file. You only have DTSTART's with DAY's , no time
and you have no DTEND.

DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20150808

DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20141106

I very much doubt that google was able to work out a start time and end time when that is not provided in the ics dump you have listed above.

Please read the RC5545 spec and try running your ics files through the ics validators.